# How can I avoid getting the same values from two different random variables but the value comes from the same list?

Tags: python-3.x, random, module

name = ("Joe", "Henry", "Jack", "Reyna", "Sage", "Jette", "Kayo")

ran_name1 = random.choice(name)

ran_name2 = random.choice(name)

print(ran_name1)
print(ran_name2)

#Henry
#Henry

How can I avoid the above same values from two different random variables?

Comment: See [random.sample](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, [random.sample](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) is probably the simplest solution:

```
ran_name1, ran_name2 = random.sample(name, 2)
```